# Create POJO from json generated by key=>value Array

Tags: java, json, pojo

I want create a pojo from a json like this

```
{
        "1": [
            {
                "idmapel": 1,
                "label": "Fisika"
            },
            {
                "idmapel": 2,
                "label": "Kimia"
            },
            {
                "idmapel": 3,
                "label": "Biologi"
            },
            {
                "idmapel": 4,
                "label": "Matematika"
            },
        ],
  "2":[
    {
        "idmapel": 1,
        "label": "Fisika"
    }
  ]
}
```

when i generate from http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ it created a 1 and 2 class, but imagine if i have more than 2 keys. i want to be able to access element by something like this `ObjectClass::getList(1)` or `ObjectClass::getList(2)`

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm imagining more than 2 keys, but nothing seems to be happening. You say it works - are you worried about scalability or something? If so, what are your concerns?

Comment: i am retrieving this from server with retrofit, the result may contain key 1,2,3, ..,n, depend on data, so what i want is i want to be able get collection by the key, if i wan to get collection with 1 key it should be accessible via ObjectClass::get(key) where key is 1, 2, or whatever the key on this json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Map` to do this.

```
Map<String, List<Pojo>> map = deserialize(jsonSring);
```

where `Pojo` is the class which has fields `idmapel` and `label`, `deserialize` is a method which deserializes the json to object and `jsonString` is the json string value to deserialize. Then you can access lists with keys

```
List<Pojo> list1 = map.get("1");
List<Pojo> list2 = map.get("2");
```

Comment: seems like best approach, will try